# The link between muscle mass and muscle strength and how to train for each

Tags: muscles, exercise

I'm getting into my fitness and am beginning to see an increase in muscle mass. However, I look at people like Bruce Lee, Elliott Hulse, Mohammad Ali and Wim Hof who are capable of incredible strength but do not look as "buff" as people like Arnold Swarzenegger. It is clear that an increase in muscle mass does not necessarily lead to an increase in strength.

How is training for strength different to training for mass?

To add a new angle to this question, is there a correlation between the two?

Comment: FYI [Correlation between muscle size and absolute strength](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/14856/630)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for fitness.SE.

Comment: I think this is perfectly at home in the biology stack exchange considering it conscerns biological functions.

Comment: Also: [How does muscle size relate to strength?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/5704/3806)